# ¿Cómo restar cantidades en stock mediante un inlineform_set?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

La idea es que desde el formulario de ventas añada los productos a vender hecho con un `inlineform_set` y al momento de guardar, se me resten los productos del stock que en mi caso es el modelo `Product`.

Estos son mis modelos:

```
class Sale(models.Model):

    n_sale        = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
    customer      = models.ForeignKey(User)

class SaleDetail(models.Model):

    relationship  = models.ForeignKey(Sale)
    products      = models.ForeignKey('products.Products')
    quantity      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,decimal_places=2)
    price         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    total         = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

class Products(models.Model):

    products    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,default='0',decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: Estás seguro de que la cantidad debe ser decimal? vas a vender 3.5 carros, o casas o cosas?

Comment: @diegueus9 tal vez 3.5 kilos de azucar, arroz o cocaína

Comment: OT: @César legalize it?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar signals, declaras en los modelos una función restar_stock y después importas:

```
 from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
```

y ejecuta la función después de guardar una venta automáticamente, algo parecido a los triggers en base de datos, puedes revisar mas información de signals en la documentación oficial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/.

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví a punta de queryset:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    id_products_sale = SaleDetail.objects.filter(relationship_id=self.object.pk)
    for x in id_products_sale:
        cant_products = Products.objects.filter(id=x.products_id)
        for z in cant_products:
            total = z.quantity - x.quantity
            update = Products.objects.values('quantity').filter(id=x.products_id).update(quantity=total)
    return reverse('detail_sale', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: +1 por autoresponder :)

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que en algún lado en tu vista tienes algo como esto para validar tanto la venta como su detalle (asumiendo que los formularios se llamen `form` y `formset` respectivamente):

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    sale = form.save()
    sale_details = formset.save()
    # ...
```

Después de guardar los detalles podrías iterar cada instancia para actualizar el stock de tu producto. Algo como esto:

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    sale = form.save()
    sale_details = formset.save()
    for sale_detail in sale_details:
        products = sale_detail.products
        products.quantity -= sale_detail.quantity
        products.save()
```

Otra opción es [sobreescribir el método](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) `save` de tu modelo `SaleDetail` para que cada vez que se guarde una instancia se actualice también el stock del producto relacionado a ese detalle.

En realidad, no se está actualizando **mediante `inlineform_set`** como sugiere el título de tu pregunta, simplemente se está haciendo **trabajo extra** después de guardar las instancias con el `inlineform_set`.