# Django.como restar cantidad ingresada menos el stock en tabla productos?

Tags: python, django

soy nuevo en python y me ha resultado complicado formular una lógica para este problema, es necesario hacer una resta de la cantidad ingresada de un articulo menos el stock que ya se encuentra en la tabla articulo. aquí las clases:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    especialidad   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    fecha_entrega  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    fecha_pedido   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
    articulo       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')    
    cantidad       = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    pendiente      = models.CharField(max_length=999,  null=True, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.articulo, self.cantidad) 

class Articulo(models.Model):
    cod_experto = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)
    info_bodega = models.ForeignKey(Bodega, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock       = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    extmin      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)
    extmax      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)



def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.nombre)
```

agradecería enormemente la solución. Exito! 
aqui el view(modificado) a punta de query set :

```
def succes(self):
    articulo   = Pedido.objects.filter(cod_experto=self.object.pk)
    for x in articulo:
        cant_articulo = Articulo.objects.filter(id=x.articulo_id)
        for z in cant_articulo:            
            total = x.cantidad - z.stock
            update = Articulo.objects.values('cantidad').filter(id=x.articulo_id).update(stock=total)
    return redirect(reverse('usuario:index.html', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}))
    return render(request, 'usuario:index.html' ,{'pk':pk})
```

no logro que funcione error:

```
Reverse for 'succes' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not     found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Solicitudes/confirmar/(?P<articulo>\\d+)/$']
url app: url(r'^confirmar/(?    P<articulo>\d+)/$',login_required(Pedidoapp.views.succes), name='succes'),
url global: url(r'^Solicitudes/', include(Pedidoapp.urls,     namespace="usuario")),
```

me marca esto como error en el index.html:

Aprobar

Answer (score 1):

Los errores que veo son los siguientes. El que te está saltando ahora mismo, es el siguiente:

> Reverse for 'succes' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not     found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Solicitudes/confirmar/(?P\d+)/$']

Lo que pasa es que en tu linea `return reverse('usuario:index.html', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})` estas enviando en el parametro `kwargs` una llave de 'pk', cuando la llave que el espera tiene que llamarse `articulo`. Eso es lo que haces cuando escribes `?P<articulo>` en la url, o bien puedes cambiar esto `?P<articulo>` por esto `?P<pk>`. Así solucionas ese error.

Segundo, si es una vista de django esa función, por lo que veo en las urls, Entonces te retornará un error. Porque no estas devolviendo un objeto del tipo HttpResponse, Si no un string, entonces lo mejor es hacer un `return redirect(reverse('usuario:index.html', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}))` si ves, añadí la funcion `redirect` que viene de `from django.shortcuts import redirect`, así no botaría ese error.

Tercero, Este sera el ultimo punto, porque no me quiero meter en tu lógica de programación. Pero veo que tienes esto:

```
...
articulo   = Pedido.objects.get(pk=1)
for x in articulo:
...
```

Esto posiblemente arrojaría un error, porque, al hacer un `get()`, este retornará un solo objeto, y al hacer un `for` sobre ese objeto, arrojaría un error alago asi.

> TypeError: 'Pedido' object is not iterable

Entonces deberías cambiar esa linea también.

Cualquier duda, comenta.

Comment: gracias estimado! según lo sugerido mi url ha quedado con ?P<pk> , pero el error sigue siendo el mismo, y marca en rojo el index: <a class="btn" btn-success" href="{% url 'usuario:succes' object.pk %}">Aprobar</a>. Reverse for 'succes' with arguments '('',)' ... editare la pregunta con las modificaciones en el queryset, con el fin de que me puedan ayudar, porfavor, saludos!

Comment: he sacado el queryset de esta pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5489/c%C3%B3mo-restar-cantidades-en-stock-mediante-un-inlineform-set