# restar items entre tablas en django python

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hola soy nuevo en esto y tengo la siguiente pregunta: ¿como puedo descontar items de las siguientes tablas? restar cantidad a EntregaItem desde la tabla DevolucionItem.

Modelos Entrega y EntregaItem

```
class Entrega(models.Model):
   creador = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   fecha_entrega = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
   contrato = models.ForeignKey('contrato.Contrato', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
              related_name='contratoentrega')

class EntregaItem(models.Model):
   entrega = models.ForeignKey(Entrega, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   item = models.ForeignKey('equipos.Equipos', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   codigo = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='-')
   cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Modelo Devolucion y DevolucionItem

```
class Devolucion(models.Model):
   creador = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   fecha_devol = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
   contrato = models.ForeignKey('contrato.Contrato', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
              related_name='contratodevol')
   dias_arriendo = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class DevolucionItem(models.Model):
   devolucion = models.ForeignKey(Devolucion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   item = models.ForeignKey('equipos.Equipos', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   codigo = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='-')
   cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Lo estoy tratando de hacer de la siguiente forma y no me resulta.

```
class DevolucionCreate(CreateView):
   def get_success_url(self):
       id_itemdevolucion = DevolucionItem.objects.\
                           filter(devolucion__contrato_id=self.contrato_id)
       for x in id_itemdevolucion:
           cant_entr = EntregaItem.objects.filter(id=x.item_id)
           for z in cant_entr:
               resta = z.cantidad - x.cantidad
               update = EntregaItem.objects.values('cantidad').\
                        filter(id=x.item_id).update(cantidad=resta)
    return reverse_lazy('devolucion:devolucion-list')
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, llevo varios días con esto :-/ (al parecer no se como hacer los querysets correctos para filtar y llegar a los campos.

Agrego la vista:

```
class DevolucionCreate(CreateView):
def get_success_url(self):
    id_itemdevolucion = DevolucionItem.objects.\
        filter(devolucion__contrato_id=self.contrato_id)
    for x in id_itemdevolucion:
        cant_entr = EntregaItem.objects.filter(id=x.item_id)
        for z in cant_entr:
            resta = z.cantidad - x.cantidad
            update = EntregaItem.objects.values('cantidad').\
                filter(id=x.item_id).update(cantidad=resta)
    return reverse_lazy('devolucion:devolucion-list')
```

Esta seria la vista que se envian los datos a traves de ajax

```
class DevolucionCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Devolucion
    form_class = DevolucionForm
    template_name = 'devolucion/devolucion_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        success_message = 'devolucion creada correctamente'
        messages.success(self.request, (success_message))
        return reverse_lazy('devolucion:devolucion-list')

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']

            if action == 'search_equipos':
                data = []
                equipos = Equipos.objects.filter(codigo__icontains=request.POST['term'])[0:20]

                for i in equipos:
                    item = i.toJSON()
                    item['text'] = i.codigo  # valores Select2
                    data.append(item)

            elif action == 'add':
                devolucion = json.loads(request.POST['listado'])
                devol = Devolucion()
                devol.nombre_empresa_id = devolucion['nombre_empresa']
                devol.n_contrato_id = devolucion['n_contrato']  # no se esta enviando este dato
                devol.servicio_id = devolucion['servicio']
                devol.fecha_devol = devolucion['fecha_devol']
                devol.numero_guia = devolucion['numero_guia']
                devol.save()
                for i in devolucion['equipos']:
                    items = DevolucionItem()
                    items.devolucion_id = devol.id
                    items.item_id = i['id']
                    items.codigo = i['codigo']
                    items.cantidad = int(i['cantidad'])
                    items.save()

            else:
                data['error'] = 'No ha ingresado nada'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        # messages.success(request, 'Listado creado correctamente')
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = 'add'
        context['det'] = []
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo, en el bucle `for` de tu vista debe ser así:

```
for i in devolucion['equipos']:
    items = DevolucionItem()
    items.devolucion_id = devol.id
    items.item_id = i['id']
    items.codigo = i['codigo']
    items.cantidad = int(i['cantidad'])
    items.save()

    # Hacemos la operacion
    entrega_item = EntregaItem.objects.get(item_id = items.item.id)
    entrega_item.cantidad = abs(entrega_item.cantidad - items.cantidad)
    entrega_item.save()
```

La única manera en que se "relacionan" por así decirlo, el modelo `DevolucionItem` y el modelo `EntregaItem`, es atraves del modelo `Equipos`, asi que atraves de el es la única manera de obtener la instancia del modelo `EntregaItem` indicada (o eso espero xD, ya que no adjuntaste el modelo `Equipos`).

Por otra parte al momento de crear la instancia del modelo `DevolucionItem`, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
items = DevolucionItem(
    devolucion_id = devol.id,
    item_id = i['id'],
    codigo = i['codigo'],
    cantidad = int(i['cantidad'])
)
```

Es mucho mas simple, ademas de que se crea la instancia y ya se inicialisan todos los atributos de una.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Julio Cesar.
Veré como me resulta y comento.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta @Julio Cesar.
Al probarlo me da un error en esa linea
devoluciones_items =DevolucionItem.objects.filter(devolucion__contrato_id=self.contrato_id) dice que contrato_id no pertenece a la clase DevolucionCreate.

Que podrá ser?

Comment: Tu eres el que obtiene los items de devoluciones así, yo solo copie esa linea de código. Y según el error es porque el atributo `contrato_id` no existe, la pregunta aquí es porque tu pusiste ese atributo... ya que si lo pusiste en tu código es que debe haber funcionado...

Comment: si hubiese funcionado, no escribiría aquí para preguntar...

Comment: Mmmm ok, entonces, hay que filtrar los items de devoluciones, por el `id` de un contrato, crees que puedes enviarle a la vista `DevolucionCreate` el `id` de un contrato, al momento de generar la URL?

Comment: seria como agregar al botón submit esto? 
{% url 'devolucion:devolucion-list' contrato.pk %}

De que forma se podrá hacer correctamente el filtro para llegar a los campos correctos? la unica relación seria itemdevolucion.devolucion.contrato o quizas tendria que relacionar de otra forma las tablas?

habia mirado esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5489/c%C3%B3mo-restar-cantidades-en-stock-mediante-un-inlineform-set

No lo logro :-(

Comment: La vista `DevolucionCreate` gestiona el modelo `DevolucionItem`? o el modelo `Devolucion`?

Comment: Gestiona ambos DevolucionItem y Devolucion.

Comment: Uy, actualiza tu pregunta y adjunta toda la vista.

Comment: Espera, puedo hacer la resta de la instancia que se esta creando? `DevolucionItem`

Comment: no entiendo esta pregunta

Comment: Osea, la instancia del modelo `DevolucionItem`, que crea la vista `DevolucionCreate`, el valor del campo `cantidad` de dicha instancia recién creada, puedo utilizarla para la operación?, es decir la resta...

Comment: si, en el post se podría creo yo. (ahi copie la vista)

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Comment: Gracias Julio Cesar..!! (estoy procesando la info jeje...)

Comment: Espectacular @Julio Cesar Funcionó..!!
GRACIAS.